# Why are Las Vegas algorithms called Las Vegas?

Tags: terminology

I just found out why `Monte Carlo` algorithms are called that (secret, codename suggested by colleague of author), which is very underwhelming by itself, but found absolutely no information about `Las Vegas`. Can anyone clarify?

I wrote an email to László Babai, the author of the term, but he is not responding. Further searching on the internet yielded no results.

Comment: Randomness -> casinos -> Monte Carlo & Las Vegas.

Comment: That's luckily untrue. `Monte Carlo` is the city where the favourite casino of the original Monte Carlo inventor's colleague, who suggested the use of the term. I understand perfectly well where does that come from, as opposed to `Las Vegas`. There are many cities with casinos around the world.

Comment: 1) Metropolis in his paper mentions "Monte Carlo" as an "_obvious_ name for the statistical method" that "have endured", also jokingly mentioning Ulam's uncle' gambling addiction in this context, 2) The _only_ thing common between Monte Carlo and Las Vegas is gambling, 3) quite many other things in science are given weird names ("Big Bang", "Ham Sandwitch Theorem", "Hairy Ball Theorem"), because scientists are mortal people with sense of humor. Invent something as influential as any of those things, and give it as dead serious name as you want. That all said, this question is off-topic on SO.

Comment: @bereal 1) Cool insight, thank you for finding out for me. But then again, it is not about `Las Vegas`, but rather about `Monte Carlo`. 2) Yes, this supports my fear of lack of description. I still hope this is somehow untrue. 3) Weird name != non-descriptive name. Each of those examples makes perfect sense to me regarding their naming. And yes, when the primary purpose of the name (that is, description of the object) is fulfilled, if you're able to combine that with a non-serious, joking intention (as those three examples), then yeah, it's fun! I agree. Not the case with `Las Vegas` though.

Answer (score 3):

Cause this two algorithm about randomize number. The authors named them by simble of gambling. these two city known as gambling so they use it.

Comment: Imagine if instad of `lossy` and `lossless` compression, we had terms like `Baden-Württemberg` compression and `Mililiani Mauka` compression. Can you explain the motivation behind not using descriptive terms?

Comment: ha ha ha , that's sounds interesting. unfortunately these cities not known enough

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Las_Vegas_algorithm#History):

> László Babai introduced the term "Las Vegas algorithm" alongside an **example
> involving coin flips**: the algorithm depends on a series of independent
> coin flips, and there is a small chance of failure (no result).
> However, in contrast to Monte Carlo algorithms, the Las Vegas
> algorithm can guarantee the correctness of any reported result.

So the author, László Babai, gived that name because of randomness of the algorithm, and the ability to apply this to a little gamble games like coin flips. He associated it with Las Vegas, the world center of gambling.

Comment: I think that's true. Cause algorithms and the cities both pointed to gambling

Comment: Well, can you explain why little-gamble games and coin flips occur only in Las Vegas, as opposed to Monte Carlo?

Comment: @CaptainTrojan name "Monte-Carlo method" was already taken. Also, you said that "
Imagine if instad of lossy and lossless compression, we had terms like Baden-Württemberg compression and Mililiani Mauka compression". The reason of why Las Vegas algorithm was not called 'gambling algo.' or something like that is big amount of other gambling-related algorithms.

Comment: But `gambling algo` makes no sense in this context, because it does **not distinguish** between MC and LV, which is the current problem of "MC" and "LV". Proper naming for MC and LV algorithms would for example be `stochastic result` and `stochastic termination` or something like that.

Comment: What we have to do now is to create an internal mapping in our brains from `LV` to `stochastic termination` and from `MC` to `stochastic result` and parse the terms `LV` and `MC` in an additional step, which is redundantly consuming both space in our heads and the time it takes to translate. After a few months of usage, people just accept `MC` and `LV` as ground truth, never question it, just "go with it", because they already went through that phase of studying. This is avoidable, I am asking, why is it not avoided then?

Comment: @CaptainTrojan I think we can explain why it's avoided by "historic reasons" or so